# Difference between isTouched and justTouched

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Basically what is the difference between `isTouched()` and `justTouched()`?

When should we use `isTouched()` and When should we use `justTouched()`?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both called when user touched but difference between them is continuity. justTouched will be called only once when user touched. But isTouched will continously called. So we can briefly say that justTouched only will be called when **new** touch event occur (holding will not give new event) however isTouched always will be called while user touching the screen (holding).

Answer (score 4):

> boolean justTouched()

Returns:
whether a new touch down event just occurred.

> boolean isTouched(int pointer)

Whether the screen is currently touched by the pointer with the given index. Pointers are indexed from 0 to n. The pointer id identifies the order in which the fingers went down on the screen, e.g. 0 is the first finger, 1 is the second and so on. When two fingers are touched down and the first one is lifted the second one keeps its index. If another finger is placed on the touch screen the first free index will be used.

Parameters:
pointer - the pointer

Returns:
whether the screen is touched by the pointer

You can check the API for all your concerns : 
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html

Answer (score 3):

`justTouched` will be called ***once***, when the *touch* occurs.

`isTouched` will be called ***multiple*** times, while the *contact* is maintained.