# Animation too fast when Gdx.input.justTouched() libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I run an animation when `Gdx.input.justTouched()`, but when the button is clicked, the animation is seen for a thousandth of a second. It's too speed, but I'm not talking about `new Animation(0.25f)`.

Example of my code:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
     boomAnimation.elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
     game.batch.draw((TextureRegion) boomAnimation.animation.getKeyFrame(boomAnimation.elapsedTime, true), 137, 121, 80, 80);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gdx.input.justTouched()` returns true only once, when the screen is touched, but not when the contact remains. Therefore the animation is just **shown for a single frame**.
Try using `Gdx.input.isTouched()` instead. This will return true, as long as the screen is touched.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388237/8178842).

**EDIT**

If you don't want the button to be held down to start the animation you can use a boolean flag to indicate whether the animation should be playing:

```
private boolean playAnimation = false;

// ...

public void render() {
  if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    playAnimation = true;
  }
  
  if (playAnimation) {
    boomAnimation.elapsedTime+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    game.batch.draw((TextureRegion) boomAnimation.animation.getKeyFrame(boomAnimation.elapsedTime,true), 137,121,80,80);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't need to hold the button down. I need an explosion animation to be displayed on click, which I read through a class where TextureRegion is located.

Comment: You could use a boolean flag. See the updated answer.